# C# WinForms Changing Control color using Button on Separate Form

Tags: c#

I am trying to change a color of an item using a button via a different form. However i cannot seem to get it to set the color even though trying to set the color on the same form seems to work but form I'm trying to get it to set on does not.

Serenity is the form name of the form im trying to get the color to apply to and UISettings is the form name im trying to apply to Serenity from and the item im trying to change color for is a panel called TopPanel.

i have tried setting the color with:

```
serenity.TopPanel.BackColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFromString(TopBarBackColor.Text);
```

and have a string to reference the ColorConverter with

```
 public static string SetValueforTopPanel = "(Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFromString(TopBarBackColor.Text);";
```

I have also tried refreshing Serenity (form im trying to get the color to apply to) and it does not seem to work, is there any way i can make this work?

Comment: You second snippet is quite confusing.  What's the value of TopBarBackColor.Text?

Comment: the value of TopBarBackColor.Text is the color i want to change it to which is 192, 186, 255

Comment: `this.BackColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFromString("192, 186, 255");` works.  Maybe "serenity" isn't the reference you think it is.

Comment: yeah doesnt work the textbox is just that number which is that, it can apply to the form with textbox just not the main form

Comment: Like I said, maybe "serenity" isn't the reference you think it is.  Show us how that variable is being declared and used on that form.

Comment: it is being referenced by  Serenity serenity = new Serenity();

Comment: Right.  That's a "new" form, not the one on the screen.

Comment: so then how would i reference the one on screen if you dont mind me asking?

Comment: You can pass a reference.  On the form, declare `Serenity serenity = null;`,  then on your form's constructor (I'm calling it Form2 since I don't know what your form is called), `public Form2(Serenity serenity) {  IntiializeComponent(); this.serenity = serenity; ... }`  The serenity form that opens this Form2 would do something like this: `Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);` etc.

Comment: ok thanks will try to see if that works

Comment: when i add ``` this.serenity = serenity;``` it throws a CS1061 error and asking for an assembly reference

Comment: You will have to edit your question with the updated code.  I can't see it from here.